# Windows Server 2008 ignores any change made to firewall

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, firewall, ping

I have been trying for the last 2 hours to make my Windows Server 2008 answer ping. I have tried almost every single solution I have found on the web, so far nothing work.

My current setup:

2 NIC (1x Internet connection, 1x Local network)
Server act as VPN server.

So I set the corresponding NIC as either Public or Private. I also enable the rule for "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request...)" for all Nic and from any IPs. I always been able to ping from the local network or the local ip while connected to the VPN. I also tried to create a specific rule for ICMP ping and disabling the firewall for all but the public nic. Regardless of all this, I still can't ping that server from Internet.

Any idea suggestion what could cause this? I have the impression that when you set the server as VPN (I switch the box on when setting it up to block everything else than VPN connection) that changing anything to the firewall setting thought mmc is pointless !?!?

Answer (score 1):

Some extra questions:

- are you having the problem both from the local network and from vpn?
- have you made sure that it is the W2K8 firewall that is refusing the ping reply? Can you reach the last hop before you get to the server?
- is it just ICMP that you're having the issue with or is the server totally unreachable?

Comment: 1. I can ping the server from local network without issues.

Comment: 1. I can ping the server from local network without issues. 2. Yes it is the winserver that block the ping because I can ping another virtual machine on the same server without issue. 3. I can connect to the vpn without problem. I also can connect to RDP with the local ip while connected to VPN.